# No DataSerializerFactory registered for namespace: 0 - hazelcast 3.5.5

Tags: deserialization, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I'm using hazelcast- 3.5.5 and hazelcast-client - 3.5.5. As per the documentation it was fixed in 3.4.x, but I'm still facing this issue in 3.5.5.

Here is my code:

```
val hazelcastConfig = new XmlConfigBuilder(System.getProperty("hazelcast.config")).build()
hazelcastConfig.setClassLoader(getClass.getClassLoader)
config.getSerializationConfig().addSerializerConfig(sc);
val instance :HazelcastInstance= Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig)
```

Below is my hazelcast.xml

```
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.5.xsd"
       xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<!--<group>-->
    <!--<name>devtestme</name>-->
    <!--<password>dev-passtestme</password>-->
<!--</group>-->
<!--<management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:3210/mancenter</management-center>-->
<network>
    <port auto-increment="false" port-count="100">5701</port>
    <outbound-ports>
        <!--
        Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
        0 or * means use system provided port.
        -->
        <ports>0</ports>
    </outbound-ports>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
            <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member-list>
                <member>myip1</member>
                <member>myip2</member>
            </member-list>
            <!--<interface>myip1 </interface>-->
        </tcp-ip>
        <aws enabled="false">
            <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
            <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
            <!--optional, default is us-east-1 -->
            <region>us-west-1</region>
            <!--optional, default is ec2.amazonaws.com. If set, region shouldn't be set as it will override this property -->
            <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
            <!-- optional, only instances belonging to this group will be discovered, default will try all running instances -->
            <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
            <tag-key>type</tag-key>
            <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
        </aws>
    </join>
    <!--<interfaces enabled="false">-->
        <!--<interface>10.10.1.*</interface>-->
    <!--</interfaces>-->

</network>

<map name="user_id">

    <map-store enabled="true">
        <!--
          Name of the class implementing MapLoader and/or MapStore.
          The class should implement at least of these interfaces and
          contain no-argument constructor. Note that the inner classes are not supported.
        -->
        <class-name>myclass</class-name>
        <!--
          Number of seconds to delay to call the MapStore.store(key, value).
          If the value is zero then it is write-through so MapStore.store(key, value)
          will be called as soon as the entry is updated.
          Otherwise it is write-behind so updates will be stored after write-delay-seconds
          value by calling Hazelcast.storeAll(map). Default value is 0.
        -->
        <write-delay-seconds>0</write-delay-seconds>
        <!--
          Used to create batch chunks when writing map store.
          In default mode all entries will be tried to persist in one go.
          To create batch chunks, minimum meaningful value for write-batch-size
          is 2. For values smaller than 2, it works as in default mode.
        -->
        <write-batch-size>1</write-batch-size>
    </map-store>
</map>
<map name="boolean_cache">

</map>
<map name="inapp_templates">

    <map-store enabled="true">
        <!--
          Name of the class implementing MapLoader and/or MapStore.
          The class should implement at least of these interfaces and
          contain no-argument constructor. Note that the inner classes are not supported.
        -->
        <class-name>myclass</class-name>
        <!--
          Number of seconds to delay to call the MapStore.store(key, value).
          If the value is zero then it is write-through so MapStore.store(key, value)
          will be called as soon as the entry is updated.
          Otherwise it is write-behind so updates will be stored after write-delay-seconds
          value by calling Hazelcast.storeAll(map). Default value is 0.
        -->
        <write-delay-seconds>0</write-delay-seconds>
        <!--
          Used to create batch chunks when writing map store.
          In default mode all entries will be tried to persist in one go.
          To create batch chunks, minimum meaningful value for write-batch-size
          is 2. For values smaller than 2, it works as in default mode.
        -->
        <write-batch-size>1</write-batch-size>
        <!--
          Remove after the idle time
        -->
    </map-store>
</map>
```

Below is the error I'm getting when I'm trying to connect to two machines

```
WARNING: [ip]:7060 [devtestme] [3.5.5] hz._hzInstance_1_devtestme.IO.thread-in-1 Closing socket to endpoint null, Cause:com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: No DataSerializerFactory registered for namespace: 0
@4000000056e9be5d36796194 com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: No DataSerializerFactory registered for namespace: 0
@4000000056e9be5d36796194   at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:98)
@4000000056e9be5d3679d6c4   at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:39)
@4000000056e9be5d3679daac   at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:41)
```

Can someone please help me to fix this, I have spent a lot of time on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does you stored objects look like?

Comment: I'm using IMap[String,Object<>]

Comment: And your Object is Serializable? Can you share the object? What does your classpath look like? Normally this error comes up if there really is something wrong but it certainly is not the hazelcast.xml, therefore please share more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a mergeStrategy for jackson libraries in my build.sbt. Removing it has resolved the issue.

Comment: With merge you mean "shading" of classes into a JAR file? PS: Glad you got it resolved :)